# Error en sentencia MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola por favor alguien me ayudac on un error que tengo en un insert HeidiSQL :

```
INSERT INTO mi_tabla (id_embarque_prog,guia_transporte,secuencia,id_expedidor,fecha_embarque,id_transportista,placa,chofer,ci_chofer,guia_remision,id_inspector,observaciones) VALUES('7','00024','24','NEGOCIO','2012-03-07 21:38','1','GGF475','077736823','1111111111','0888036823','','PRUEBA')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me lanza el siguiente error:

Error de SQL (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`_mi_db`.`mi_tabla`, CONSTRAINT `mi_tabla_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_inspector`) REFERENCES `mi_otra_tabla` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) */

Comment: Parece que el problema es la referencia del campo id_inspector con la tabla mi_otra_tabla, al ver la sentencia SQL de INSERT ese campo esta vacio,

Comment: Estás pasando un String vacío en tu INSERT para el campo `inspector_id` cuando está esperando una dato de tipo TINYINT.

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate que todos los valores que hacen referencia a una llave foránea existan en la tabla a la que hacen referencia.

Por ejemplo, el valor '00024' del campo "id_embarque_prog" debe existir en la tabla en donde dicho campo es la llave primaría.